# Why ordinal number has been used in "fourth helpings at every meal"?

Tags: articles, numbers

> Mrs Weasley fussed over the state of his socks and tried to force him to eat **fourth helpings** at every meal.

The word "**helping**" is a countable noun, meaning *a single portion of food taken at a meal*. So, I might think **four helpings at every meal** seems to be more reasonable. On the other hand, usually the ordinal number is preceded by the definite article "**the**", like "*the fourth helpings*". Any thoughts?

Comment: Ordinals are commonly used when discussing helpings at mealtimes in Britain, especially school meals, where an extra helping can be called "seconds" or more formally "a second helping". She tried to make him eat "fourths", having already succeeded with seconds and thirds.

Comment: The lack of a definite article is entirely appropriate.

Comment: "Helping" is one of those weird words which must be *in addition to* the first serving.  There is no such thing as "first helpings".  As such, I think second/third/fourth helpings would tend to suggest "fourth of several helpings" and therefore plural.  Though maybe this is just specious reasoning.

Comment: @Neil I think in some circumstances such a wedding buffet or on a cruise ship it might be possible to say one was going for a first helping of food. Anticipating  that with the abundance of food on offer and a large enough appetite you would go for more helpings later.

Comment: I don't think any of the four proposed answers so far answer it. Conjecture: "fourth helpings" is a somewhat clarified version of "fourths", since "fourths" is fairly uncommon, relative to "thirds" and "seconds" which are very common and therefore clear. So the question becomes: why do we say "seconds" and "thirds" to mean "a second helping" and "a third helping"?  My conjecture there is that it's simply a kind of contraction: "would you like second" sounds jarring due to number mismatch, so "would you like seconds" is used instead even though it doesn't quite make sense if you think about it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are correct that "*four* helpings every meal" probably makes more sense.  This particular use refers to the common idiomatic expression "second helping", meaning a second portion of whatever was served the first time around.

> "Would anyone like a **second helping**?" Mom asked, standing over the table with a full plate of pancakes.  We all yelled for more.

"Thirds" and "fourths" are also not uncommon when feeding hungry teenagers.

With this sentence the trick is to recognize that Rowling writes "at *every* meal", meaning there were multiple meals.  At each of these meals Mrs. Weasley offered Harry "a fourth helping" (after, presumably, the first, second and third helpings) -- which, in the plural, becomes "fourth *helpings*"

(Edit) Just to add detail, the use of "fourths" add colorful imagery to the scene, where we can picture Mrs. Weasley insisting that Harry take *seconds*, then *thirds*, and then even more after that.

Comment: Can we understand this plural in a way that Mrs Weasley offered Harry a fourth helping a day, and since it's multiple days, therefore "fourth helpings at every meal". Does that sound reasonable?

Comment: @dan  Yes, that's the general idea (although I would assume they ate three meals each day). It's still somewhat colloquial writing, but kids' books are often written in an informal style.

Comment: but T said in his comment: ""fourth helpings" is actually a singular noun, a name for that particular helping in a sequence of helpings.  Compare **matins**.  *Fourth helpings **was** more than even he could manage.*" I'm a bit confused.

Comment: @dan I'm not sure I agree with Tᴚoɯɐuo here.  But I could be wrong.

Comment: If it was "forced him to eat four helpings" it could (perhaps more likely would) mean that force was required for all four. But "forced him to eat fourth helpings" is consistent with the first three being entirely voluntary.

Comment: I wouldn't say one is more grammatical than the other; I would say they have different emphases. Helpings are countable (cardinal), but also generally occur in sequence (ordinal).

Comment: @eques  Ok, "grammatical" probably isn't the right word.  Edited to "makes more sense".

Comment: Can we also put "force him to eat a fourth helping at every meal"?

Comment: @dan  Yes.  To my ear that actually sounds better ... but then I'm not a billionaire author  :)

Answer (score 3):

Compare:

> Would you like a second helping?

or

> No second helpings!  We are saving the rest of the cake for your cousins, who will be back from the game momentarily.

Without the article the ordinal is a determiner, here referring to a specific helping in the sequence of helpings.

Comment: Can we also put "force him to eat a fourth helping at every meal"?

Comment: if it's "a specific helping in the sequence of helpings", why does it put as plural, "fourth helpings".

Comment: "fourth helpings" is actually a singular noun, a name for that particular helping in a sequence of helpings.  Compare **matins**.  *Fourth helpings **was** more than even he could manage.*

Comment: I don't see how "fourth helpings" is a singular noun. It seems to violate Ocham's Razor to assert any special grammatical understanding here.

Comment: @eques did you look up **matins** in a couple of good dictionaries?

Comment: Yes but that doesn't help with the phrase "fourth helpings". The fact that some words exists as plurals only or are plural in form but singular in meaning says nothing about this one.

Comment: @eques:  I disagree. Compare also **laud** and plural **lauds** where plural **lauds** is the *name* for a particular service in a series of canonical hours, and takes a singular verb.  *Lauds **is** ...*  The analogy holds here with **helpings** which are established "canonical" parts of a meal.

Comment: Perhaps you are missing my point. I'm not asking about "matins" or "lauds" as a service being a plural name in singular usage (in English). I'm asking why you are asserting that "fourth helpings" should be understood that way. You are in effect asserting that plural-as-singular-name is a productive function. But we have dinner not "have dinners" (usually) and we have dessert not have desserts.

Comment: I think you are missing my point about the canonical series.  A *name* is being given to the canonical meal event, and that explains why there's no article and why an ostensibly plural noun can accept a singular verb.

Comment: @eques: I think you're approaching this backwards, working from the facts on the ground out to language, when what is happening is that language is imposing itself upon the facts on the ground (or here, on the dinner table).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84929/discussion-between-eques-and-tomauo).

Comment: If we take it as a name, can we hyphen it as a compound noun word, fourth-helping or fourth-helpings?

Comment: In this context, *fourth-helpings* (plural) yes, but *fourth helping*, no.

Answer (score 3):

I think that the expression is related to

[**second helping**](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/second_helping)

> A **second portion** of the same thing, usually of food; seconds; **refill**.
>   *He had already eaten six sausages, but that did not stop him reaching
>   for a second helping.*

If we extrapolate a bit, we can conclude that Mrs Weasley was trying to force Harry to eat four times each dish served per meal: the original, the second helping, the third helping and the fourth helping. Remember that they think that he was starving before they rescue him from the Dursleys.

Comment: It might be a bit diferent in this case. It put "fourth helping**s**", instead of "fourth helping".

Comment: @dan I think that the plural establishes that Mrs Weasley try to force Harry to have a fourth ending per dish served in a single meal. A fourth ending of soup or salad, a fourth ending of the main course and a fourth ending of dessert. That would make three fourth endings (plural) per meal.

Comment: Yeah, that's a reasonable explanation. It seems that there are variety of interpretations for it so far. :) On the other hand, a helping might include everything already like salad, soup, main course, etc.

Comment: see this part from Andrew's answer: "the common idiomatic expression "second helping", meaning a second portion of whatever was served the first time around"

Comment: @dan Yes, you may be right if we are talking about a buffet. You can serve whatever you like in the second helping. But if you dinner in your home with your parents, did they serve all the dishes at the same time, including desserts?

Comment: If you look into the response from others, they think "A second helping" is the same as "second helpings".

Answer (score 2):

I think the issue here is that the helpings are served *sequentially*, not *concurrently*.

If someone puts the equivalent of four servings of food on one large plate, it would be completely correct to describe that as "four helpings".  However, if you are served one helping, eat it, and then get *another* one, the next one would be your "second helping"; if you eat that and get yet another, it would be your "third helping"; etc.  Ordinal numbers are used because the helpings are served *in an order*, not all at once.

Comment: You have a good point. Well, why is there no article 'the'? usually, we say: the first one, the second one, ... Why not say the second helping?